# How to keep the first filename of each ID from a huge list using PHP or regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have this huge list of filenames in the format `car-id_picture-id.jpg` like below (only a part of it)

```
1201_3.jpg
1201_4.jpg
1201_5.jpg
1201_6.jpg
1201_7.jpg
1201_8.jpg
1201_9.jpg 
1240_15.jpg
1240_16.jpg
1240_17.jpg
1240_18.jpg
1240_19.jpg
1240_2.jpg
1240_8.jpg
1240_9.jpg
1511_0.jpg
1511_1.jpg
1511_7.jpg
1511_8.jpg
```

What I want is

```
1201_3.jpg
1240_15.jpg
1511_0.jpg
```

My aim is using a php script or even a regex in Notepad++ to have a list of only one image per carID and preferrably the first on the list of each car.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: I have updated the question with the wanted output.

Comment: why a regex? the first of every image set has the `(...)` stuff going on, so look lines with a `(`, then use a simple substring operation to get everything up to the first space char.

Comment: It think he added that to show what he wants. It surely can be done with awk.

Comment: @MarcB Sorry for my mistake of misunderstanding. The (1201) next to the filename is to help you that there is a new id. It does not appear in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the below regex with global and multiline flags

```
^((\d{4})_\d+.jpg)(\n\2.+)+
```

and replace with `$1` or you could take the captured value from group 1.

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/wY9qY2/1)

Comment: Sorry for my mistake of misunderstanding. The (1201) next to the filename is to help you that there is a new id. It does not appear in the list.

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos also check my demo

Comment: I'd say that using this regexp you will get the last matches for each carId instead of the first ones.

Comment: Even though it works, it seems that it gets the last filename instead of the first filename it meets

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos trying. Just a minute

Comment: Cool, it works. Please another one modification, there are several filenames like `5585-072.jpg 5594-5376094_2_b.jpg 5661-DSC01750.jpg`. How can I include the `-` and `- or _ followed by letter`?

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
<?php

$images = "
1201_3.jpg
1201_4.jpg
1201_5.jpg
1201_6.jpg
1201_7.jpg
1201_8.jpg
1201_9.jpg
1240_15.jpg
1240_16.jpg
1240_17.jpg
1240_18.jpg
1240_19.jpg
1240_2.jpg
1240_8.jpg
1240_9.jpg
1511_0.jpg
1511_1.jpg
1511_7.jpg
1511_8.jpg
";
$images_array = array_filter(explode("\n", $images));

$output = array();
foreach ($images_array as $img) {    
  $matches = array();
  preg_match('%([^_-]+)_.*%', $img, $matches);      
  $car_id = $matches[1];
  if(isset($output[$car_id])) continue;
  $output[$car_id] = $img;
}

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake of misunderstanding. The (1201) next to the filename is to help you that there is a new id. It does not appear in the list.

Comment: It works, thank you. But I noticed one thing in this huge list, there are several filenames like these `5585-072.jpg
5594-5376094_2_b.jpg 5661-DSC01750.jpg` That means that it must run for the files that have `-` instead of `_`. All the ids have 4 digits at the begining. Can this be edited?

Comment: edited - that should do it, alternatively if you know that it will always be a 4 digit car id, you could use substring, but that will break as soon as the number goes to 5 digits. Probably a micro optimisation that's not worth the risk

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider if you really need regex...
Sometimes is preferable (e.g. in terms of processing time) to use string functions. For instance, something like:

```
$s = file("images.txt");
$array = array();
foreach($s as $line) {
 $carId = substr($line,0,strpos($line,"_"));
 if(!array_key_exists($carId,$array)) {
   $array[$carId] = trim($line);
 }
}

var_dump(implode("\n",$array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
$images = "
1201_3.jpg
1201_8.jpg
1201_9.jpg
1240_15.jpg
1240_16.jpg
1511_0.jpg
1511_1.jpg
";

$array = array();

  $foo = explode('.jpg', $images); 
  foreach($foo as $bar) { 
    $digi = substr(trim($bar), 0,4) . "<br />"; 
    if(!in_array($digi, $array)) {
        array_push($array, $digi);
        echo $bar . ".jpg <br/>";
    }
  }


//ouput
1201_3.jpg 
1240_15.jpg 
1511_0.jpg
```